# dattables: column rendering with link

Tags: datatables

could be a cakewalk for some people but being very new to data tables, i am finding it difficult to achieve the following:

my json data structured in csv looks this will be:

```
EmpId, EmpNum, EmpName
1,E01,John
2,E02,Doe
3,E03,Bill
```

I want my datatable in the following way

```
EmpNum| EmpName
---------------
E01   | John
E02   | Doe
E03   | Bill
```

The hyperlink reference on E01 should be `emprof.aspx?empid=1`, for E02 it should be `emprof.aspx?empid=2`... and so on...

i know `columnDefs` is a way forward for me but somehow unable to crack it.

Any quick help please. thank you.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve it? Please edit your question and add this information, also, to improve the chances of getting a good anwser, please take a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on the help pages.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're returning json in this format:

```
[
    {
        "EmpId": 1,
        "EmpNum": "E01",
        "EmpName": "John"
    },
    {
        "EmpId": 2,
        "EmpNum": "E02",
        "EmpName": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "EmpId": 3,
        "EmpNum": "E02",
        "EmpName": "Bill"
    }
]
```

Then you're right about the columns, Something like this would do it:

```
"columns": [
    {
        "title": "EmpId",
        "visible": false,
        "data": "EmpId"
    },
    {
        "title": "EmpNum",
        "data": "EmpNum",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
            return "<a href='emprof.aspx?empid=" + row.EmpId + "'>" + row.EmpNum + "</a>";
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "EmpName",
        "data": "EmpName"
    }
],
```